# SQL Server 2005 Currency Format with comma's and period

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to cast a money field in SQL Server 2005 to format it

Ex) the field contains:

```
99966.00
```

and we want to return it in this format: $99,966.00

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The data layer should not bother to format data for the presentation layer...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
'$' + convert(varchar,cast(SalesProducts.Price as money),-1) as Price
```

This works

Comment: ...until someone changes the regional settings on your SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

**try this it works for SQL Server 2008 and below (2012 have already a FORMAT() function that you can use)**

this will only works for data type Money and SmallMoney

```
declare @v money -- or smallmoney
set @v = 1000.0123
select convert(varchar(25), @v, 0)
select convert(varchar(25), @v, 1)
select convert(varchar(25), @v, 2)
select convert(varchar(25), @v, 126)

select '$' + convert(varchar(25), @v, 0)
select '$' + convert(varchar(25), @v, 1)
select '$' + convert(varchar(25), @v, 2)
select '$' + convert(varchar(25), @v, 126)
```

HOPE THIS HELP!

Answer (score 1):

What about CHF 9'666,00 or £99,966.00?

"Currency" is a number in the database: *not* a regional or locale setting

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
declare @d float = 34.5

select format(@d, '0.0')  -- 34.5
select format(@d, '00')  -- 35
select format(@d, '0000') -- 0035
select format(@d, '0000.00') -- 0034.50
```

Good?