# c#Syntask near ','

Tags: c#, types, varchar

```
projeservices.update("UPDATE ProjeEkle SET  Yuklenici='" + txtyuklenicig.Text
    + "',İhaleBedeli='" + Convert.ToDecimal(ntxtihalebedelig.Text.Replace(",", ".")) 
    + "',İhaleTarihi='" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtpihaletarihig.Text) 
    + "',SozlesmeTarihi='" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtpsozlesmetarihig.Text) 
    + "',İsinSuresi='" + ntxtisinsuresig.Text 
    + "',TeslimTarihi='" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtptxtteslimg.Text) 
    + "',BaslamaTarihi=,'" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtptxtbaslamag.Text) 
    + "',BitisTarihi='" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtptxtbitisg.Text) 
    + "' WHERE İsinAdi='" + txtisinadig.Text + "'");
```

Where's my fault?

Comment: You'd find it a lot easier to read if you used String.Format .. what are the values of each of your text boxes? youve certainly sent text to the decimal field what if I typed "frog" in there? you're sending all as text....

Comment: This is the least you can expect from the string concatenation (format or not) USE PARAMETERS

Comment: What date format you are passing for datetime fields?

Comment: I added up image my form face

Answer (score 0):

If `ntxtihalebedeli.Text` like 123,456 replace the ',' with '.'.

```
..."','" + ntxtihalebedeli.Text.Replace(",", ".") + "','"...
```

And perhaps replace this

```
"','" +ntxtisinsuresi.Text + "','"
```

with

```
"'," + ntxtisinsuresi.Text + ",'"
```

Comment: ntxtihalebedeli.Text.Replace(",", ".") right answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this code?

```
projeservices = new HProje();
            projeservices.insert("INSERT INTO ProjeEkle(İsinAdi,Yuklenici,İhaleBedeli,İhaleTarihi,SozlesmeTarihi,İsinSuresi,TeslimTarihi,BaslamaTarihi,BitisTarihi)values('" + txtisinadi.Text + "','" + txtyuklenici.Text + "','" + ntxtihalebedeli.Text + "','" + dtpihaletarihi.Text + "'," + Convert.ToIn(dtpsozlesmetarihi.Text) + ",'" + ntxtisinsuresi.Text + "','" + dtptxtteslim.Text + "','" + dtptxtbaslama.Text + "','" + dtptxtbitis.Text + "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that the value passed to İsinSuresi or İhaleBedeli isnt considered numeric. this is most likley a problem in the decimal value if the intake decimal is using the wrong punctuation. if not, maybe looking for a solution in the conversion in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245663/sql-server-format-decimal-places-with-commas) article can help