# conversion between nvarchar float and language impact

Tags: sql, sql-server

when i do

```
select cast('2,2' as float)
replace('2,2' , ',' , '.' ) is needed before casting
```

i have the following error " Error converting data type varchar to float."
because there is the comma.

when i do

```
 select cast('2.2' as float)
```

the result is "2,2" with a comma

i am a bit lost with that since i integrate excel files with french formatted numbers: commas "," instead of "." so i have tons of theses errors

thankss!

Comment: What language is set for the OS?

Comment: SSMS is displaying the result according to the regional settings on your machine, but the SQL Server you are running against has different (likely default, American) regional settings.

Comment: what is actual question ?

Comment: @Ven I think the OP wants to either always see `2.2` or always see `2,2`. Probably the latter.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Aaron: Do u think he wants to see it in output or input ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server format decimal places with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245663/sql-server-format-decimal-places-with-commas)

Comment: what type of output you need ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118057/convert-string-numeric-values-with-comma-as-decimal-separator-to-numeric10-2

Comment: @Ven Your guess is as good as mine. At the root I'm sure they just want to understand why it's different.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I guess excel import into SQL server  is causing 2,2 instead of 2.2 , he will simply need to replace or cast it at the import layer

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#float-and-real-styles) states that the notation needed to be used for casting numeric/float characters to numeric format is **Scientific Notation**

Numbers are displayed with *6,720,000,000 =>    6.72×109* in [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Thus the answer is : Regardless of Regional Settings input format is always fixed to Scientific Notation

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
declare @rate double
set @rate = 1.954
select     FORMAT(@Rate, 'G', 'fr-fr') as formatted_decimal

1,9540
```

will print

Answer (score -1):

please use this i think this will help you

```
select cast(replace('2,2',',','.') as float)
```